# What language should I use to build a cross platform mobile app for a project that already has a fully functioning webapp and api?

Tags: react-native, mobile, kotlin, flutter

We have a fully built out webapp that has a java API, I want to build a cross platform mobile app that can utilize this already existing java api. Is this possible? I would prefer to do as little work rewriting the backend as possible.

I have spent hours googling it and can't find anyone who tried to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: You could use Java if you have extensive experience. Xamarin (primarily c#) is also a good option.

My 2 cents: I would recommend using the native languages instead of doing cross-platform.

Your Java will work for Android, and Java to Objective-C for iOS is not that big of a jump.

I used to work at a development firm and the mobile devs often had to do MORE work to make something cross-platform instead of just going for native.

** answer based on experience dealing with mobile devs; I'm a web dev **

Answer (score 0):

I'm no sure that's what you are looking for but you can try using [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) and build a hybrid app, using this you would have to change basically nothing on your back end and could reuse part of your front end.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Java API running locally somehow? or called remotely? Just curious why it's mentioned if it's purely a back-end service, since most any front-end framework should be reasonably agnostic of what's running behind the scenes if it's only interacting with it through API calls.

React Native, specifically using the "create-react-native-app" tool to create a simple react native app that uses expo to build its binaries is shockingly easy to transition to from react.

There's almost no setup to get going and Expo (included when you use create-react-native-app to initialize your project) allows you to build for IOS and Android without even necessitating the use of android studio or xcode for anything other than the final submission to the app stores.

I've used react native and expo extensively as a react web developer and have been extremely surprised with how little extra I've had to learn to get our app published to google play and app store.

If your app needs a lot of access to native device functionality then there may be better options but I can't imagine learning objective-C or using any of the other cross-platform frameworks will be as easy for 99% of use cases.

Given the EXTREME differences between ios and android app design, I'd strongly caution against going the "pure native" route, as you're essentially doubling up the amount of work by maintaining two completely separate builds of your app and not really gaining anything in terms of functionality unless your app relies heavily on many of the native features of the device (camera, accelerometer, local storage, etc).